# XQuery ancestor axis doesn't work, but explicit XPath does

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic, axes

Consider the following `XML` snippet:

```
<doc>
    <chapter id="1">
        <item>
            <para>some text here</para>
        </item>
    </chapter>
</doc>
```

In `XQuery`, I have a function that needs to do some things based on the **ancestor** chapter of a given "para" element that is passed in as a parameter, as shown in the stripped down example below:

```
declare function doSomething($para){
    let $chapter := $para/ancestor::chapter
    return "some stuff"
};
```

In that example, **$chapter** keeps coming up empty. However, if I write the function similar to the follwing (i.e., without using the **ancestor axis**), I get the desired "chapter" element:

```
declare function doSomething($para){
    let $chapter := $para/../..
    return "some stuff"
};
```

The problem is that I cannot use explicit paths as in the latter example because the `XMl` I will be searching is not guaranteed to have the "chapter" element as a grandparent every time. It may be a **great-grandparent** or **great-great-grandparent**, and so on, as shown below:

```
<doc>
    <chapter id="1">
        <item>
            <subItem>
                <para>some text here</para>
            </subItem>
        </item>
    </chapter>
</doc>
```

Does anyone have an explanation as to why the axis doesn't work, while the explicit XPath does? Also, does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

---

### SOLUTION:

The mystery is now solved.

The node in question was re-created in another function, which had the result of stripping it of all of its ancestor information. Unfortunately, the previous developer did not document this wonderful, little function and has cost us all a good deal of time.

So, the ancestor axis worked exactly as it should - it was just being applied to a deceptive node.

I thank all of you for your efforts in answering my questions.

Answer (score 5):

The ancestor axis does work fine. I suspect your problem is namespaces. The example you showed and that I ran (below) has XML without any namespaces. If your XML have a namespace then you would need to provide that in the ancestor **XPath**, like this: `$para/ancestor:foo:chapter` where in this case the `prefix _foo_ is` bound to the correct namespace for the chapter element.

```
let $doc := <doc>
    <chapter id="1">
        <item>
            <para>some text here</para>
        </item>
    </chapter>
</doc>

let $para := $doc//para
return $para/ancestor::chapter
```

RESULT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter id="1">
  <item>
    <para>some text here</para>
  </item>
</chapter>
```

Comment: Thank you, Clark. I have verified that $para is what I expect, via error logs in MarkLogic 4.2. I know that it SHOULD work, but for some reason it doesn't. A lot of headscratching is going on here.  :^)

Comment: I suspect your problem is namespaces. The example you showed and that I ran has XML without any namespaces. If you XML does in fact have a namespace then you would need to provide that in the ancestor XPath, like this: $para/ancestor:foo:chapter where in this case the prefix foo is bound to the correct namespace for the chapter element.

Comment: @mahdaeng Alternatively, you may have declared a default element namespace for some specific namespace at the top of your module, while your XML has none or a different one.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen, for mentioning the possibility of namespaces causing a problem here. In this document, however, there are no namespaces being used.

Answer (score 2):

These things almost always boil down to namespaces! As a daignostic to confirm 100% that namespace are not the issue, can you try:

```
declare function local:doSomething($para) {
    let $chapter := $para/ancestor::*[local-name() = 'chapter']
    return $chapter
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems surprising to me; which XQuery implementation are you using? With BaseX, the following query...

```
declare function local:doSomething($para) {
    let $chapter := $para/ancestor::chapter
    return $chapter
};

let $xml :=
  <doc>
    <chapter id="1">
        <item>
            <para>some text here</para>
        </item>
    </chapter>
</doc>
return local:doSomething($xml//para)
```

...returns...

```
<chapter id="1">
  <item>
    <para>some text here</para>
  </item>
</chapter>
```

Comment: Thank you, Christian. I'm using whatever implementation of XQuery that is provided by MarkLogic 4.2.

Comment: Yah I concur this works fine using the query evaluator at http://developer.marklogic.com/try/ninja/page2 which is running on MarkLogic 5.  What version of 4.2 are you using?

Comment: I've heard that the above code works fine in 4.2-4 so something environmental is likely going on to confuse things for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect namespaces too. If `$para/../..` works but `$para/parent::item/parent::chapter` turns up empty, then you know it's a question of namespaces.

Look for an xmlns declaration at the top of your content, e.g.:

```
<doc xmlns="http://example.com">
  ...
</doc>
```

In your XQuery, you then need to bind that namespace to a prefix and use that prefix in your XQuery/XPath expressions, like this:

```
declare namespace my="http://example.com";
declare function doSomething($para){
  let $chapter := $para/ancestor::my:chapter
  return "some stuff"
};
```

What prefix you use doesn't matter. The important thing is that the namespace URI (`http://example.com` in the above example) matches up.

It makes sense that `../..` selects the element you want, because `..` is short for `parent::node()` which selects the parent node regardless of its name (or namespace). Whereas `ancestor::chapter` will only select `<chapter>` elements that are not in a namespace (unless you have declared a default element namespace, which is usually not a good idea in XQuery because it affects both your input and your output).